# Understanding Quasi-self-similarity of the Julia Set (Falconer)

Tags: analysis, fractals

Here's an excerpt from the book:

> The highly intricate structure of the Julia set illustrated in Figure 0.6 stems from the single quadratic function $f(z) = z^2 + c$ for a suitable constant $c$. Although the set is not strictly self-similar in the sense that the Cantor set and von Koch curve are, it is ***quasi-self-similar*** in that arbitrarily small portions of the set can be magnified and then distorted smoothly to coincide with a large part of the set.

I don't know if the author rigorously defines quasi-self-similarity later in the text, but the "definition" above seems vague. In the particular example of the Julia set, what is meant by *"arbitrarily small portions of the set can be magnified and then distorted smoothly to coincide with a large part of the set"*? What exactly are these distortions, and could someone help me understand with pictures how the magnified part on distortion coincides with a part of the set? How much do I need to magnify, and what part?

Most of these questions are easy to answer in the case of Cantor sets, von Koch curve, and the Sierpinski triangle - since these are self-similar fractals. Quasi-self-similarity isn't that easy a nut to crack, it seems.

[image]

I also came across this animation for $f(z) = z^2 - 1$, but I'm not sure what it's trying to convey.

[image]

---

**References:**
Falconer, Fractal Geometry.

Comment: Did you try googling "quasi-self similar set"? Doing this I found [*A note on Hausdorff measures of quasi-self-similar sets*](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1987-100-01/S0002-9939-1987-0883425-3/) by John McLaughlin (1987) and [*Not all Julia sets are quasi-self-similar*](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1997-125-03/S0002-9939-97-03706-4/) by Pentti Järvi (1997) and [**Dimension Theory and Fractal Constructions Based on Self-Affine Carpets**](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masmas/Fraser_thesis.pdf) by Jonathan MacDonald Fraser (2013) (see pp. 34-35 and the references he gives there).

Comment: The Julia set of $f_c(z)=z^2+c$ is the invariant set of something like an IFS composed of two branches of the inverse of $f_c$, as illustrated in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2742947/self-similarity-in-fractals/2743052#2743052).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro, Thanks for sharing the references. I'll check them out! They are all very lengthy, so in case you'd like to summarize any important parts from them in the form of an answer, I would appreciate it.

Comment: The animation indicates that the Julia set is composed of two copies of itself under the functions $\pm \sqrt{z+1}$.